# What would seas of non-water liquids be like?

Tags: planets, chemistry

First off, is a sea of a non-water liquid even plausibly likely to occur on a given exoplanet? Secondly, what non-water liquids would be most likely to form into large bodies? How would those liquids act in ways different from water and how would that affect a planet's geology?

Comment: Can you give us more details about the "given exoplanet"? Else it will be impossible to give an answer passing the book test.

Comment: Methane & Ethane lakes are found on Titan. Carbon Dioxide oceans may have existed on Venus if it were cooler. I was unable to see renditions of how it looks from the surface or under it, but Ralleigh scattering as well as soil erosion by those liquids do occur. Compared to watet, they are not polar solvents, so you are unlikely to find salts like in sea water. Organic and non-polar molecules, on the other hand are more soluble.

Comment: There are plenty of options, some already mentioned by Christmas Snow. You would have to narrow down some more specific conditions for us to be able to check for a liquids fitting your expectations.

Comment: Obligatory xkcd what-if reference: https://what-if.xkcd.com/50/

Comment: @cobaltduck Thanks, I'm really enjoying this.